# Within ML CFA with categorical data (polychoric correlation), are there not different thresholds for both the within and between level?

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor, polychoric

I am currently studying multilevel confirmatory factor models of categorical data. In the context of CFAs, categorical data is often analysed through polychoric correlations. Within polychoric correlations, one assumes that each of the observed ordinal variables are governed by a normally distributed continuous latent variable. Model estimation therefore also implies the estimation of thresholds associated with each answer category (the total number of thresholds is equal to the total number of categories minus 1).

Now, as I understand within multilevel confirmatory factor models one generally estimates factor loadings for both the within as well as the between level. Also, one estimates covariance matrices for both the within as well as the between level. As I understand, however, thresholds associated with polychoric correlations will only be estimated at the between level. For example, Mplus highlights that "The thresholds of variables on the between and within levels exist only on the between level". My question is given that multilevel confirmatory factor models implies covariance matrices at the within and the between level, why should one not assume there are also different thresholds for the within and between level?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am in a similar situation where I need to calculate the within correlation matrix by hand and I have no idea how to do that for polychoric correlations